# How find the largest numbers $\lambda(n)$ such $\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_{k}|^2\ge\lambda(n)\cdot\min_{1\le k\le n}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}$

Tags: inequality

Assmue that give the positive integer number $n$,Find the largerst the constant $\lambda(n)$,such for any complex $z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{n}(z_{i}\neq 0,i=1,2,\cdots n)$,have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_{k}|^2\ge\lambda(n)\cdot\min_{1\le k\le n}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}$$
where define $z_{n+1}=z_{1}$

This problem is from china TST 2014,

before I have post this simarler problem:
[Finding the biggest $k$ such $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_{n-1}^2+x_n^2} \geq k\min(|x_1-x_2|,|x_2-x_3|,\dots,|x_{n-1}-x_n|,|x_n-x_1|)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619432/finding-the-biggest-k-such-sqrtx-12x-22-dotsx-n-12x-n2-geq-k-mi?lq=1)

and

[How find this inequality $\max{\left(\min{\left(|a-b|,|b-c|,|c-d|,|d-e|,|e-a|\right)}\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611302/how-find-this-inequality-max-left-min-lefta-b-b-c-c-d-d-e-e-a-ri)

In fact, this two different problem.

maybe this idea can help solve this problem? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mu=\min_{1\le k\le n}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}$.
When $n$ is even, achille hui’s proof can be used again without changes :
we have

$$
|z_{2k}|^2+|z_{2k+1}|^2 =\frac{|z_{2k}-z_{2k+1}|^2+
|z_{2k}+z_{2k+1}|^2}{2}\geq \frac{|z_{2k}-z_{2k+1}|^2}{2} \geq \frac{\mu}{2}
$$

and summing on $k$ we have that 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} |z_k|^2 \geq \frac{n\mu}{2}$. This becomes an equality
when $z_k=1,z_{2k+1}=-1$ for every $k$, so $\lambda(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ when
$n$ is even.

When $n$ is odd, however, achille hui’s proof uses the ordering of the real
numbers which does not exist in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: so How to solve complex?

Comment: @math110 Speak English please

Comment: Today I re-examine this question and find that achille proof is not right for odd $n$,

Comment: this post have result,$\lambda{n}=\dfrac{n}{2(1+\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}})}$ when $n$ is odd, see  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h582165p3440492,but this link have no true proof